# Unable to adapt codes to convert Tensorflow model for Google Earth Engine (EEification)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory, gcloud

I tried to adapt the [example from Colab github](https://colab.research.google.com/github/google/earthengine-api/blob/master/python/examples/ipynb/Earth_Engine_TensorFlow_AI_Platform.ipynb) to train a model in Tensorflow and then convert the model into a GEE-friendly format (EEification) for export to use in GEE code editor.

However, for some reason, the EEification codes were unable to run successfully. I got this error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.ai-platform.versions.create) 
Error: model server never became ready. Please validate that your model file or container configuration are valid
```

Upon debugging this error, I get:

```
DEBUG: Making request: POST https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token
DEBUG: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): oauth2.googleapis.com:443
DEBUG: https://oauth2.googleapis.com:443 "POST /token HTTP/1.1" 200 None
DEBUG: https://us-central1-ml.googleapis.com:443 "GET /v1/projects/bucket_name/operations/model_name?alt=json HTTP/1.1" 200 None
```

Why is there no response from the server when I (mostly) changed only the variables from the examples to my objects (bucket_name & model_name are replacements for my actual bucket & model name)? The only major change that I can think of is the usage of Project ID instead of Project Name because the code refused to run if I were to use the Project Name.

What is the error here about and how can I troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue and I solved it by ensuring that the tensorflow runtime in my colab notebook is same as the one used for the model on the AI platform (2.1 in case of the notebook that you shared). Try doing the following where you import tensorflow:

```
!pip install tensorflow==2.1.0
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
```